# Place jQuery created html into specific div

Tags: jquery, html

I have an empty div that is written purely in HTML:

I then have some jQuery:

```
var prevLink = '<a class="back" href="#">Back</a>';
var nextLink = '</a><a class="next" href="#">Next</a>';
var navHTML = '<div class="prev-next">' +
                         prevLink +
                         nextLink +
                      '</div>';
var prevLink = '<a class="back" href="#">Back</a>';
var nextLink = '</a><a class="next" href="#">Next</a>';
var navHTML = '<div class="prev-next">' +
                         prevLink +
                         nextLink +
                      '</div>';
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
            // init
            $('#customisesystem > div')
                .hide()
                .prepend(navHTML);
            $('#first-step .prev').remove();
            $('#last-step .next').remove();

            // show first step
            $('#first-step').show();

            $('a.next').click(function(){
                var whichStep = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');

                if( whichStep == 'first-step' )
                {
                    // validate first-step
                }
                else if( whichStep == 'second-step' )
                {
                    // validate second-step
                }
                else if( whichStep == 'last-step' )
                {
                    // validate last-step
                }

                $(this).parent().parent().hide().next().show();
            });

            $('a.back').click(function(){
                $(this).parent().parent().hide().prev().show();
            });
        });
```

How can I place the back and next buttons created by the jQuery within the progress-buttons div?

Answer (score 2):

you can do this by `html()`

like

```
 $("id or class of div").html("html created")
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I do that in relation to my code? It's the placement that I'm struggling with.

Comment: There's some much other jQuery relating to the buttons that I'm finding it confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) jquery function.

Comment: I have this part in it `.prepend(navHTML);` but the variable is throwing me, how can I include the variable and target the correct div? p.s That is where it's putting the buttons on the page isn't it?